# My VS CODE extension code runner isnt working

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, vscode-code-runner

Hi my issue is that in my visual studio code, my code runner extension doesn't provide any output. I've looked at a bunch of tutorials and have done everything, research, download node.js,and saves the file as a javascript file and verify paths.

I entered " console.log("Hello")
Its prints this out
[Running] node "c:\Users\NAME\Untitled-1.js
[Done] exited with code=0 in 0.202 seconds

And nothing [image]

Please help idk what I'm doing wrong

Comment: i've done every single things these people wrote as answers and it didn't change a thing. Were you able to do it?

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you haven't saved the file.

Try saving the file and then run with Code Runner.

**Tip:** You can enable `Save before Run` settings so that it gets saved every time before running the file.

```
File -> Preferences -> Extensions -> Run Code Configuration -> Save File Before Run
```

[image]

Comment: code runner says it will run code that is not saved yet.

Answer (score 1):

in my case solution was to uncheck "Show Execution Message" check box in Run Code configuration.

setting

[image: 1]

result

[image: 2]

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to run `node -v` and `npm -v` in command prompt window to see if you have them installed

the output must be like this

```
C:\Users\Anonymous>node -v
v16.14.0

C:\Users\Anonymous>npm -v
8.3.1
```

and if there is a problem it might be from your paths ("Edit system environment variables" in windows search) or you haven't installed npm or node.

Comment: I have these versions and still get the same result as OP