# The Javascript code excited without any output

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, output

The Visual Studio Code was functioning flawlessly until yesterday; however, it is currently not displaying any output. I am utilizing Code Runner for JavaScript and other purposes.
[Output not being displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MYzws.png)

Despite attempting to disable it, a new issue arises: the 'Run' icon disappears when Code Runner is disabled. Even after re-enabling it, the output remains absent. I have also attempted uninstalling and reinstalling it, but the problem persists. I would greatly appreciate all of your assistance in resolving this matter.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My VS CODE extension code runner isnt working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71919602/my-vs-code-extension-code-runner-isnt-working)